# jquery fullcalendar and week calendar

Tags: jquery, user-interface, calendar, fullcalendar

How to get week calendar add event function in fullcalendar?

Comment: This description is not enough to get anyone to help you. Please describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the API of FullCalendar [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/)

The author pretty much has already explained quite a lot there. If you have any specific question, please start asking a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

Solvedd by a little research :)

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=215&q=week%20calendar&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars